# C++ Rounding Numbers without ceiling or floor

Tags: c++, casting, rounding

I'm attempting the following question from DS Malik's *C++ Programming: From Problem Analysis to Program Design*

Chapter 2, Question 7

> Write a program that prompts the user to input a decimal number and
>   outputs the number rounded to the nearest integer.

My program so far

```
 #include <iostream>

 using namespace std:cout;
 using namespace std:cin;

 int main()
  {
    double decimalNum;
    cout << "Please enter a decimal number: ";
    cin >> decimalNum;
    return 0;
  }
```

Is it possible to round the number to an integer without using floor or ceiling? Please note that I just started C++ programming a few days ago so nothing too overly complex please.

Comment: Add 0.5 and cast to an integral type.

Comment: try to store it in a integer type variable with explicit conversion

Comment: @EmadS: I see that you are new to StackOverflow. If any answer satisfies your query, I suggest that you accept it as the correct answer by clicking on the green tick next to the answer. This will allow the question to be marked as answered, and give more focus to other unanswered questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, add `0.5` and typecast it to as `int`.

The reason behind adding `0.5` is to ensure that numbers are rounded off as opposed to the decimal part being truncated. So, `6.6` will be truncated to `6`, but rounded off to `7`.

Typecasting is the procedure of changing types. Some types are compatible with each other, but are different. For example, `int`, `float`, `double`, `long` all represent numbers. So when you write an `int + float`, the compiler first converts the `int` to a `float` automatically, and then does the operation. This is known as typecasting. You can do it explicitly, or the compiler does it many times.

So, to wrap it up, adding `0.5` will help you round off correctly, and typecasting will change the type.

Answer (score 2):

You can try the following code -

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    double decimalNum;
    cout << "Please enter a decimal number: ";
    cin >> decimalNum;
    int roundNum = decimalNum + 0.5;
    cout << "The nearest rounded number : " << roundNum << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding 0.5 then calling [`modf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/modf/) may be your best bet - the integral part is returned as a `double` so you still get correct results for numbers outside the range of even a 64-bit integral type.  There are a lot of other options also available in the [cmath header](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/).

Comment: Note that cplusplus.com has been proven to not be a reliable source.